# Python matplotlib UnicodeEncodeError when resetting rcParams in interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, python-unicode

Python shows a UnicodeEncodeError when resetting rcParams and using Latex in interactive mode. I use PyCharm 2018.1.4 together with iPython 5.8. Python version is 2.7.15, Matplotlib version is 2.2.2.

Input 1 creates the plot, but gives the UnicodeEncodeError:

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2

In[2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  ...: import numpy as np
  ...: 
  ...: plt.ion()
  ...: plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
  ...: 
  ...: x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000) * 2*np.pi
  ...: y = np.sin(x) * 10**(-10)
  ...: 
  ...: plt.plot(x,y)
  ...: plt.savefig('/home/proxauf/test_unicode1.png')
  ...: plt.close()
  ...: 
  ...: plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False
  ...: 
  ...: print "plot 1 successful"
  ...:
```

Output 1:

```
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
plot 1 successful
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 519, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 433, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1475, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2607, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1192, in draw
    renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1130, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 922, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 309, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 232, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 501, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 361, in make_dvi
    texfile = self.make_tex(tex, fontsize)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 259, in make_tex
    fh.write(s.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2212' in position 230: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Input 2 creates the plot without the error:

```
In[3]: plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
  ...: 
  ...: plt.plot(x,y)
  ...: plt.savefig('/home/proxauf/test_unicode2.png')
  ...: plt.close()
  ...: 
  ...: print "plot 2 successful"
  ...:
```

Output 2:

```
plot 2 successful
```

I don't understand this at all. In both cases the plots are created as they should be (with Latex mode, see below), but with Input 1 python has issues when resetting the matplotlib rcParams. However the plot could be created without problems in non-Latex format when `text.usetex = False` from the start as well. What is happening here? Any possible fixes? The error is not really a problem (program works fine), but a nuisance that I want to get rid of.

[image: Plot 1 (identical to plot 2)]

**Update:** Error seems to appear only when switching (within one code execution) from `text.usetex = True` to `text.usetex = False` and only when `axes.unicode_minus = True`. The other directions or combinations work without issues.

**Update 2:** I have reproduced the error when using iPython 5.8 outside of PyCharm.

Comment: `plt.close()` should close the figure. Any parameter setting which happens afterwards should not affect a plot which isn't there any more because it has been closed. I also cannot reproduce this behaviour outside of PyCharm; I would hence suspect that there is some problem within PyCharm.

Comment: Can you reproduce it within PyCharm though? Agreed on your statement about that the plot should principally not be affected, but unfortunately it is.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot use PyCharm currently to test this. But if you can reproduce this *outside* of PyCharm, you may open an issue at the matplotlib issue tracker.

Comment: I actually could reproduce this with IPython version 5.8 (the same that PyCharm uses) outside of PyCharm.

Comment: Wow ok, so I tested only with IPython 5.3, where this works fine, but indeed, when using IPython 6.4, I can reproduce the error. As said in this case it would probably be good to have an issue about it on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

Comment: The issue can also be reproduced with IPython 4.1.2. So this seems to be indeed version-dependent. Anyways, as a workaround, when inserting `plt.rcParams["axes.unicode_minus"] = False` after the `plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = False`, the code works also when executed in one go.